# Emails sent from PHP are 7 hours behind

Tags: php

Our site is hosted on Godaddy linux dedicated virtual hosting server. Site is run on PHP. All the emails sent from within the code are showing up in the email box as sent 7 hours before.

I tried setting "date" header in the mail function but that didn't help. In SMTP setting in PHP.ini it says localhost. Server time is set correctly and hence I just cannot find where to change that.

Maybe I am thinking we will migrate our emails to Google apps. Can Google apps settings be used as SMTP to send emails from a Godaddy server for example?

Thanks for any response.

Comment: Sounds to me like the issue is the server time on your Godaddy hosted server. Depending on what protocol you are using to send email from PHP, it may or may not be dependent on you server's time settings. Check that out first.

Comment: Are you using a relay? If so, that can get queued depending on how many people are using it.

Comment: I am not sure how to tell that, from what I can see we are using SMTP service

Comment: With a server with Go Daddy your emails would be sent through a relay server.  Are your emails being delivered 7 hours later than when sent or is just the timestamp reflecting a different timezone than where you are located?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see:

```
 echo date();
```

See what you get on that.

It might be related with the **timezone** in php.ini. Set it to where you are at.

Comment: date ("m/d/Y H:i:s") shows me Arizona time as the server is hosted there (godaddy). 

After I do
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

Time shows as EST time but the emails continue to be behind

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the setting in Php.Ini you might want to try setting the time zone using http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php on the mail script

Comment: Even after adding the manual setting for timezone to New York, the emails continue to show 7 hours behind. Now thats weird because it doesn't matter if the timezone is set to Arizona vs. New York, time on the email continues to show 7 hours behind. So somewhere else they are getting timestamped

Comment: Go daddy might be the culprit.. U set the date header then immediately print out the time zone with one of the date parameters see what it outputs

Comment: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/setting-server-timezone/.. If you are on a shared server you can try that.. Try sending a support ticket let them know your issues

Answer (score 0):

On tope of your page put `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');`and try

Comment: Yes I did date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York').. doesn't help